# High CPU usage in C# multi-threaded code

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

I don't have much knowledge in writing good multi-threaded code. I have just recently started working on a project where it is necessary. I have written the following code, which works as I want it to, however, the CPU usage is very high. I am assuming it is due to how I am using the threads. If anyone could point out the flaw in the below code and let me know how to fix it so the CPU usage is not so high, I would greatly appreciate it.

```cs
var numberOfMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfMinutesToRun"]);
var traversals = DbLayer.GetTraversals().ToList();
var numberOfThreads = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfThreads"]);
var threads = new List<Thread>(numberOfThreads);
var counter = 1;
var s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
var sync = new object();
while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(numberOfMinutes))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < (numberOfThreads - threads.Count); i++)
    {
        var counter1 = counter; // due to closure.
        var traversal = traversals.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == counter1);
        var threadStart = new ThreadStart(new CallHelper(traversal).Migrate);
        var i1 = i;
        threadStart += () =>
                       {
                            threads.RemoveAt(i1);
                       };
        threads.Insert(i, new Thread(threadStart) {IsBackground = true});
        threads[i].Start();
        lock (sync)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 6)
            {
                counter = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
s.Stop();
```

I updated the code to show, what I hope, is required to help me. The traversals collection contains only 6 items. The counter is there to ensure that the threads rotate through each of the 6 items in the traversals collection. The CallHelper class is just performing a very long running task on each traversal. The application is designed to perform the long running task on 6 different objects using a configurable amount of threads for a configurable amount of time. Hopefully I have filled in enough of the blanks.

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete, and verifiable example that reproduces the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do. What is the goal here? What does `CallHelper().Migrate` do? Whhat is the purpose of the `counter`? Why are you using a `while` loop and a `for` loop to generate the threads?

Comment: How many threads are you using? and post code about threadStart.

Comment: You need to figure out how to attach a profiler to your code and profile it. That's the best way to figure out the problem.

Comment: You should be using the Task Parallel Library to manage threads, not trying to manually do it. (Especially if you're not an expert at this.)

Comment: If its not a critical loop then a Thread.Sleep(1) shall bring down the CPU utilization to a great extent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific to OP, and not useful to anyone else. (Sorry, I couldn't find the meta post discussing the use of close reasons for this, although I've read it recently.)

Comment: using a lot of CPU is a good thing in many cases. You multi thread in order to get the max amount of work from the CPUs, you are executing several things at once in parallel => cpu use goes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of resources available on line for writing [good](http://etutorials.org/Programming/visual-c-sharp/Part+II+Advanced+C/Chapter+10+Advanced+Topics/Writing+Multithreaded+Code/) and efficient multi-threaded code. "Good" generally refers to working and robust code. For efficient code, use [embedded](http://www.bing.com/search?q=embedded%20writing%20efficient%20code%20threading&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=embedded%20writing%20efficient%20code%20threading&sc=1-41&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=2720C3BBFA0B4EFB8E105F70E43FC93C) resources.

I only scanned your code but can see a variety of issues and can offer suggestions.

1. Use a thread pool. Building and tearing down threads is very expensive.
2. Repeat the loop as infrequently as possible (as mentioned above).
3. Use sleeps and not busy loops when you need to delay.
4. Use non-trivial code to test efficiency. If you are testing against trivial code, your utilization will be dominated by program (not just thread) setup and tear down, something that is very expensive and will dominate the cpu utilization.
5. Measure the utilization of the code you are interested in and exclude that which you are not, such as application setup and tear down.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because you are correct. There are a couple of "issues" with the above code, and, because your input was very helpful. I have rewritten the inner loop and the CPU usage is minimal but the throughput is very good. I also added a Thread.Sleep(1000) at the end of the inner loop. I am going to also take your advise and look up how to use a "thread pool". Thank you very much.